# How to send response from servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, testng

I have a Ajax call sent from browser to a Servlet. At Servlet some value is calculated say A. My query is how can I validate this A. I am using TestNG from where the browser starts but after that control shifts to Servlet. How should I return the value from Servlet such that in TestNG I can fetch it and validate.

Answer (score 0):

solutions I can think of:

```
(1)
```

Bypass the servlet: put your business calculations in a separate method/class, and test directly. This might be enough **if** the focus is on the business code (while the servlet layer does trivial tasks such as extracting simple request parameters). E.g:

```
// logic - assuming this is the test focus, with interesting cases such as insufficient funds, limited account etc.
public class MyBank{
   public void transferFunds(int fromAccountId, int toAccountId, int dollars)...   
}
// servlet that happens to have trivial code that isn't so important to test
public class MyServlet{
    ...
         int fromAccountId=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("fromAccountId"));
         int toAccountId=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("toAccountId"));
         int dollars= Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("dollars"));
         bank.transferFunds(fromAccountId, toAccountId, dollars)
}
```

(2) Use an embedded server, like Jetty. 
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html
From your unit test you just launch a jetty (using 'new Server()'...) and tell it to execute the servlet.

(3) you can also invoke your servlet, injecting it with mock request/response/session  etc. Spring, for example, has such mock objects.
So it's something like:

```
HttpServletRequest mockReq=new MockHttpServletRequest();
HttpServletRequest mockResp=new MockHttpServletResponse();
new MyServlet().service(mockReq, mockResp);
```

Just note it might require some tweaking depending on what your servlet needs - e.g. request parameters, session (the mock request has methods to add them)

Comment: Tx Pelit, but my concern is not to access  servlet which can be doen through mock or other ways. Actually i need to read what the servlet/ Business logic class calculated so I just need to return that value somehow. I need  returned value in a java program.

Comment: Can't you write your business layer to return this value? E.g. in class "MyBank" above, have it return YOUR_DATA instead of "void"?

Comment: Actually I am using TestNG, so once the browser starts from test method,  then control reaches Servlet , the control flow do not return back at TestNg test method.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're using the 'mock request' approach (mentioned in section 3 above)? So your TestNG class contains something like "myServlet.service(mockReq, mockResp)"?

Comment: In that case, the servlet will just write its response into your MockHttpServletResponse... so back in your TestNG you can test the content that was written there. The exact test depends on your implementation of the MockHttpServletResponse, e.g. if using spring (org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse) then you ask "String str=myMockResp.getContentAsString()"